# Linq to Entity Paging With Large dataset too slow

Tags: c#, mysql, linq-to-entities

I'm analyzing player data over millions of matches from an online game.  I'm trying to page data into memory in chunks to reduce load times but using `OrderBy` with skip/take takes way too long (20+ minutes even for smaller queries).

This is my query:

```
var playerMatches = (from p in context.PlayerMatchEntities
                     join m in context.MatchEntities 
                        on p.MatchId equals m.MatchId
                     where m.GameMode == (byte) gameMode
                        && m.LobbyType == (byte) lobbyType
                     select p)
                     .OrderBy(p => p.MatchId)
                     .Skip(page - 1 * pageSize)
                     .Take(pageSize)
                     .ToList();
```

`MatchId` is indexed.

Each match has 10 players, and I currently have 3.3 million matches w/ 33 million rows in the `PlayerMatch` table, but data is being collected constantly.

Is there a way to get around the large performance drop caused by OrderBy?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956335/extremely-poor-linq-query-performance-when-using-skip-take-for-paging) is similar but didn't seem to be resolved.

**Edit:**

This is the SQL query generated:

```
SELECT
`Project1`.`AccountId`, 
`Project1`.`MatchId`, 
`Project1`.`PlayerSlot`, 
`Project1`.`HeroId`, 
`Project1`.`Item_0`, 
`Project1`.`Item_1`, 
`Project1`.`Item_2`, 
`Project1`.`Item_3`, 
`Project1`.`Item_4`, 
`Project1`.`Item_5`, 
`Project1`.`Kills`, 
`Project1`.`Deaths`, 
`Project1`.`Assists`, 
`Project1`.`LeaverStatus`, 
`Project1`.`Gold`, 
`Project1`.`GoldSpent`, 
`Project1`.`LastHits`, 
`Project1`.`Denies`, 
`Project1`.`GoldPerMin`, 
`Project1`.`XpPerMin`, 
`Project1`.`Level`, 
`Project1`.`HeroDamage`, 
`Project1`.`TowerDamage`, 
`Project1`.`HeroHealing`
FROM (SELECT
`Extent2`.`AccountId`, 
`Extent2`.`MatchId`, 
`Extent2`.`PlayerSlot`, 
`Extent2`.`HeroId`, 
`Extent2`.`Item_0`, 
`Extent2`.`Item_1`, 
`Extent2`.`Item_2`, 
`Extent2`.`Item_3`, 
`Extent2`.`Item_4`, 
`Extent2`.`Item_5`, 
`Extent2`.`Kills`, 
`Extent2`.`Deaths`, 
`Extent2`.`Assists`, 
`Extent2`.`LeaverStatus`, 
`Extent2`.`Gold`, 
`Extent2`.`GoldSpent`, 
`Extent2`.`LastHits`, 
`Extent2`.`Denies`, 
`Extent2`.`GoldPerMin`, 
`Extent2`.`XpPerMin`, 
`Extent2`.`Level`, 
`Extent2`.`HeroDamage`, 
`Extent2`.`TowerDamage`, 
`Extent2`.`HeroHealing`
FROM `match` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `playermatch` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`MatchId` = `Extent2`.`MatchId`
 WHERE ((`Extent1`.`GameMode`) = 2) AND ((`Extent1`.`LobbyType`) = 7)) AS `Project1`
 ORDER BY 
`Project1`.`MatchId` ASC LIMIT 0,1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to have a VIEW that does the join and indexes the appropriate columns and then create a Table-Valued Function that uses the VIEW and returns a TABLE with only the page data.
You'll have to manually write the SQL query for the paging, but i think it would be faster.
I haven't tried something like that so i can't be sure there is gonna be a big speed boost.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include enough information to help you so I'll suggest.
One way to avoid order by is to store rows in a table already in the order. I suggest 'MatchId' is a primary key and a *clustered index* of MatchEntities. That means MatchEntities.MatchId is stored physically sorted. If you switch join streams to pull the sorted stream first and additive stream second you avoid expensive sorting.

Like this:

```
var playerMatches = (from m in context.MatchEntities     // note the switch: MatchEntities goes first
                 join p in context.PlayerMatchEntities
                    on p.MatchId equals m.MatchId
                 where m.GameMode == (byte) gameMode
                    && m.LobbyType == (byte) lobbyType
                 select p)
                 // .OrderBy(p => p.MatchId) // no need for this any more
                 .Skip(page - 1 * pageSize)
                 .Take(pageSize)
                 .ToList();
```

Also see a query plan to find out how the query is executed by the database, what type of join is being used, etc. Maybe your original query does not exploit sorting at all.